# Adding a column using HIVE

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I have following data table.

```
ID salary occupation

1  5000   Engineer       
2  6000   Doctor         
3  8000   Pilot          
4  1000   Army           
1  3000   Engineer       
2  4000   Teacher        
3  2000   Engineer       
1  1000   Teacher        
3  1000   Engineer       
1  5000   Doctor
```

Now I want to add another column flag to this table so that it looks in the following way.

```
ID salary occupation Flag

1  5000   Engineer   0    
2  6000   Doctor     0    
3  8000   Pilot      0    
4  1000   Army       0    
1  3000   Engineer   1    
2  4000   Teacher    1    
3  2000   Engineer   1    
1  1000   Teacher    2    
3  1000   Engineer   2    
1  5000   Doctor     3
```

Now how can I update my original table to the above format using HIVE?

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have data in your files for the additional column you can use Add Column clause for Alter Table. 
In your example do something like this:

```
Alter table Test ADD COLUMNS (flag TINYINT);
```

Or you can try REPLACE COLUMNS as well:

```
Alter Table test REPLACE COLUMNS (id int, salary int, occupation String, flag tinyint);
```

You might need to load(overwrite) your dataset again though(just a speculation!!!).

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely add new columns in HIVE table using alter command as told above

```
hive>Alter table Test ADD COLUMNS (flag TINYINT);
```

In Hive 0.13 and earlier releases, column will have NULL values but HIVE 0.14.0 and later release, you can update the column values using  [UPDATE command](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update)

Another way is, after adding column using ALTER command, you can overwrite the existing data with the new data(having Flag column)

```
 hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'flagfile.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE <tablename>;
```